# Ruby - How to redefine class methods?

Tags: ruby

How do I redefine a class method in ruby?

say, for example, I want to redefine the method `File.basename("C:\abc.txt")` How do I do it?

This doesn't work:

```
class File
  alias_method :old_bn, :basename

  def basename(*args)
    puts "herro wolrd!"
    old_bn(*args)
  end
end
```

I get  `: undefined method 'basename' for class 'File' (NameError)`

btw, I'm using `JRuby`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`alias_method` is meant for instance methods. But `File.basename` is a class method.

```
class File
  class << self
    alias_method :basename_without_hello, :basename

    def basename(*args)
      puts "hello world!"
      basename_without_hello(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

The `class << self` evaluates everything on the "class level" (Eigenklass) - so you don't need to write `self.` (`def self.basename`) and `alias_method` applies to class methods.

Comment: Personal preference. If I monkey-patch I tend to search for `class File` in my `core_ext` and want to find all modifications there. Also it's easier to google `class << self` and find out what that means if new people start working on that code and haven't seen that idiom yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
class << File
  alias_method :old_bn, :basename
  def basename(f)
    puts "herro wolrd!"
    old_bn(*args)
  end
end
```